# How to Execute Macro through Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, macros

I have created one macro in Teradata, now wish to call that macro through Stored Procedure (in Teradata only). The SQL part belongs to macro.

I wrote this procedure in case if execution of macro is not possible through procedure.

Kindly suggest both the option.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE MDM_STAGE.match_sqls_proc
    (
        in  fname VARCHAR(30),
        in  match_frst_name VARCHAR (100),
        in  lname VARCHAR(30),
        in  match_last_name VARCHAR (100),
        in  addr1 VARCHAR(1000),
        in  zip_cd_base varchar(10),
        in  email VARCHAR(30),
        in phone VARCHAR(30),
        out msgs VARCHAR(10)
    --  INOUT errstr VARCHAR(30)
    )
    begin

        DECLARE  SQLTEXT2 VARCHAR (10) ;
        DECLARE TBL_COUNT INT ;

     select count (*) into :TBL_COUNT from 
    (
    SELECT
    CUST.CUST_ID,
    CUST.FRST_NAME,
    CUST.MATCH_FRST_NAME,
    CUST.LAST_NAME,
    CUST.MATCH_LAST_NAME,
    CUST.GNDR_TYPE_CD,
    STREET_ADDR.ADDR_LN_1_TXT,
    STREET_ADDR.ADDR_LN_2_TXT,
    STREET_ADDR.ADDR_LN_3_TXT,
    cast (coalesce (STREET_ADDR.ADDR_LN_1_TXT,'') ||   ' ' || coalesce 
 (STREET_ADDR.ADDR_LN_2_TXT,'' ) as varchar (1000)) as addr,
   STREET_ADDR.CITY_NAME,
   STREET_ADDR.POSTL_CD,
   STREET_ADDR.STREET_ADDR_ID,
   STREET_ADDR.ADDR_SBTYPE_CD,
   ELCTRNC_ADDR.ELCTRNC_ADDR_ID,
   ELCTRNC_ADDR.ELCTRNC_ADDR_SBTYPE_CD,
   ELCTRNC_ADDR.ELCTRNC_ADDR_TXT,
   TLPHN_NUM.TLPHN_LN_NUM,
   TLPHN_NUM.TLPHN_NUM_ID

  FROM
  MDM_STAGE.REF_CUST_V   CUST

  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  MDM_STAGE.REF_STREET_ADDR_V  STREET_ADDR
  ON
  CUST.CUST_ID = STREET_ADDR.CUST_ID

  AND
 --RDM_ADDRSIM (STREET_ADDR.ADDR_LN_1_TXT ,'2285Main Street' ) =1
  RDM_ADDRSIM ( cast (coalesce (STREET_ADDR.ADDR_LN_1_TXT,'') ||   ' ' || 
  coalesce (STREET_ADDR.ADDR_LN_2_TXT,'' ) as varchar (1000))  ,:addr1)   =1
  AND
  SUBSTR(STREET_ADDR.POSTL_CD,0,6) = (:zip_cd_base)

  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  MDM_STAGE.REF_ELCTRNC_ADDR_V ELCTRNC_ADDR
  ON
  CUST.CUST_ID = ELCTRNC_ADDR.CUST_ID
  /*AND
  STREET_ADDR.ADDR_SBTYPE_CD = ELCTRNC_ADDR.ELCTRNC_ADDR_SBTYPE_CD*/
  AND 
  ELCTRNC_ADDR.ELCTRNC_ADDR_TXT= (:email)

  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  MDM_STAGE.REF_TLPHN_NUM_V TLPHN_NUM
  ON
  CUST.CUST_ID = TLPHN_NUM.CUST_ID
  /*AND
  STREET_ADDR.ADDR_SBTYPE_CD = TLPHN_NUM.ADDR_SBTYPE_CD*/
  AND
  TLPHN_NUM.TLPHN_LN_NUM = (:phone)

  WHERE 
 (RDM_sndx(COALESCE(CUST.Match_FRST_NAME,CUST.CUST_ID))=RDM_sndx(:match_frst_name) 
   AND
   RDM_sndx(COALESCE(STRTOK(CUST.Match_LAST_NAME,' ',1),CUST.CUST_ID))=RDM_SNDX(:match_last_name) 
)
  AND
  (
  TLPHN_NUM.CUST_ID IS NOT NULL
  OR
  ELCTRNC_ADDR.CUST_ID IS NOT NULL
  OR
  STREET_ADDR.CUST_ID IS NOT NULL
  )  A
  ;

     IF   ( TBL_COUNT > 0 ) THEN  SET SQLTEXT2 = 'Match'  ;

        ELSE 
            SET Msgs = 'Non-Match' ;
            END IF;     
    end;
```

Error message -

> SPL1027:E(L88), Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3707):Syntax error, expected something like an 'EXCEPT' keyword or an 'UNION' keyword or a 'MINUS' keyword between ')' and the word 'A'.'.

No idea, what to add between the word 'A' and ')'. Tried all the possibility but not successful. Not sure how to pass the value of SQL into the 'count' as  later call procedure condition is based on that count only.

Comment: It looks like at least one missing `)`

Comment: Could you please specify where it is missing. I tried, but still error occur.

Comment: Before that ) and A

Comment: Thanks. it is working now. Please suggest how to view the output after passing input parameters.